# How to check if custom field exists in this widget query

Tags: custom-field, widgets, query

How can I include this (or something similar)

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true) ) { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", $single = true); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('');?></a>

<?php } else { ?>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail('');?>

<?php } ?>
```

Into this simple widget query?

```
query_posts('post_type=sponsors&meta_key=_vof_sponsor_level&meta_value=Gold');
if (have_posts()) : 
    echo "<div class='imageshadow sponsorwidgetslides'>";
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_post_thumbnail('sponsorwidget');
endwhile;
    echo "</div><!--/.imageshadow-->";
echo "<a class='widgetlink' href='";
bloginfo('url');
echo "/sponsors'>View all Sponsors &raquo;</a>";
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

So basically, if the custom field "url" exists it outputs the featured image wrapped in an anchor tag, but if the custom field doesn't exist it just outputs the featured image.

Also, I know it's not ideal using query_posts, and that get_posts would be better, but I'm under orders here.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but does the code above not work if put in your widget code?

Comment: I tried it this morning but it didn't seem to. I'm not all that used to custom widgets, so having to echo the markup, etc. is a bit new to me

Comment: Read somewhere that it could be $post->ID causing the problem (never playing with widgets so I don't know), but did you try using your code above in your widget, replacing $post->ID with get_the_ID()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it now, but the following should work...

```
    query_posts('post_type=sponsors&meta_key=_vof_sponsor_level&meta_value=Gold');
    if (have_posts()) : 
        echo "<div class='imageshadow sponsorwidgetslides'>";
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
           if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true) ) { ?>
             <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url',true); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('sponsorwidget');?></a>

          <?php } else {
              the_post_thumbnail('sponsorwidget');
            }
        endwhile;
        echo "</div><!--/.imageshadow-->";
        echo "<a class='widgetlink' href='";
        bloginfo('url');
       echo "/sponsors'>View all Sponsors &raquo;</a>";
   endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

I've not come across any problems with `$post->ID`, but from what Shane has just commented, you could change that to `get_the_ID()`